# How to constraint item position in flutter?

Tags: flutter, user-interface, widget, row

I try to make a list of widget. It look like this:

[image]

I know of no such thing as Constraint Layout in flutter. But I need something to position my arrow icon in a fixed position on the right. To put it simple, this is my widget code:

```
Row(
children:[
  SizedBox(),
  Column(),//this is all the item on the left
  Spacer(),
  Expanded(// this is the heart and arrow button
   child: Column()
  )
]
)
```

I notice that if my column on the left get too wide, my arrow and heart icon is shifted out of line.
[image]

How to put my icon in fixed position to the right?

Comment: Use `Stack` along with the `Positioned` widget so that you can place the arrow at the extact position. Or wrap the above column too with `Expanded` and set a flex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here try this, You have to wrap middle column with expanded so it will take the maximum space available

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

/// This is the main application widget.
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text(_title)),
        body: const Center(
          child: MyStatefulWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

/// This is the stateful widget that the main application instantiates.
class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

/// This is the private State class that goes with MyStatefulWidget.
class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  bool isChecked = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: 10,
      itemBuilder: (_, index) => Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),border: Border.all(width: 1.5)),
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Container(
              width: 25,
              height: 40,
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Column(children: [
              //put your children here
              ]),
            ),
            //this will be always on right
            Column(
              children: [
                Icon(Icons.heart_broken),
                Icon(Icons.chevron_right),
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```